# Svchost high CPU from Microsoft.BingWeather app errors

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-store, svchost

Yesterday svchost.exe started using high CPU (25% continuously)

I did some research a figured out the case of the issue. The following error is in the Event Viewer every half an hour since this issue started.

> Activation of app Microsoft.BingWeather_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App failed with error: This app does not support the contract specified or is not installed. See the Microsoft-Windows-TWinUI/Operational log for additional information.

The TWinUI/Operation log has the following two errors alternating every half an hour:

> The app Microsoft.BingWeather_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App is not registered for the Windows.BackgroundTasks contract or is not installed.
>
> Activation via contract helper of the app Microsoft.BingWeather_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App for the Windows.BackgroundTasks contract failed with Class not registered.

I’ve tried the following:

- Launch and close the weather app. It works correctly.
- Added “ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES” read & execute access to
  %AppData%\Local\Packages
- Added an account to the windows store
- Ran windows store troubleshooting and reset the windows store
- Ran a full antivirus scan and Malawarebytes scan. Both found nothing.
- Restart after each of the above options.
- Running shell commands for window store. This returned the below error. ‘C:\WINDOWS\WinStore\AppxManifest.xml’ does not exist
  [image: AppxManifest not found]
  OS: Windows 10 Pro
  Version: 1607
  OS Build: 14393.1066

Comment: use 1703 ISO to upgrade to Creators Update, this reinstall all apps

Comment: any update? Have you upgraded to 1703?

Comment: @magicandre1981, I'm a little busy right now as. I'll post an update as soon as I try this. Probably last weekend of May or first weekend of June.

Comment: I’m back from vacation now so I tried this out. 

I reinstalled windows saving apps and data via this link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10 
This did not fix the issue. 

Then I tried restarting, updating the OS and restarting again. This still did not fix the issue. 

Then I noticed that Microsoft now lets me uninstall the app despite it being one of the apps which came with windows. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the weather app. This did not fix the issue. 

Then I tried uninstalling the app and did not reinstall. This finally fixed the issue.

Comment: hm, I personally don't use this app garbage so I have no real idea how to really fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A future windows update gave the ability for me to uninstall this app. After I uninstalled the app this issue was fixed as long as I didn't reinstall it.

I believe this was the May 2017 update.

Comment: A Windows update *removed* your ability to install the app after which you *uninstalled* the app? That doesn't make sense; can you [edit] to clarify? Further, instead of saying a "future" update, please be more specific about exactly which update you're referring.